# Analyzing time complexity for change making algorithm (Brute force)

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, asymptotics, recurrence-relation, coin-change

I'm new to analyzing time complexities and I have a question. To compute the nth fibonacci number, the recurrence tree will look like so:
[image: Fibonacci recurrence tree]

Since the tree can have a maximum height of 'n' and at every step, there are 2 branches, the overall time complexity (brute force) to compute the nth fibonacci number is `O(2^n)`.

Now, looking at the [coin make change problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). If the coin denominations are `[1, 5, 10, 25]` and the input number to make change for is `'C'`, the recurrence tree should look something like this:
[image]

In this case, the tree can have a maximum height of `'C'` and the number of branches per step is 4 (The number of coin denominations we are given. Let's call this `'n'`). With that being the case, shouldn't the time complexity be `O(n^C)`. I read everywhere that the time complexity is `O(C^n)`. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, when computing the $n$-th fibonacci number $F(n)$, the number of branches (leaves) is not $2^n$, but exactly $F(n)$. But you can say it is $O(2^n)$.

As for the coin change problem it is not $O(n^C)$. $n^C$ is a polynomial, while the number of branches in the tree  grows exponentially. In other words, given $n$ number of coin denominations and constant $C$, each node has no more than $C$ children, and so the number of branches/leaves is at most $C\times C\times \dots C$ ($n$ times). In fact the actual number of branches is less than $C^n$, but is definitely bounded from above by $C^n$, and so is $O(C^n)$ (recall that big-O denotes the upper bound of a function).

Comment: The logic of branching_factor_max ^ max_height of recursive tree = max_number_of_recursive_calls (aka max number of nodes in tree) is correct so I must be missing something. 

Assuming the base algorithm is we make denomination.length recursive calls with N - denomination as target until target amount is 0 or below 0, then the max_branching_factor = denomination.length and the max_height assumes a poss denomination of 1 so is N. Why does this not lead to time complexity of denomination.length^N? Your logic makes sense, but I’m still struggling to find the error with mine or OPs.

Comment: @Morgan I think this answer is wrong. It is known that for a perfect n-ary tree the number of nodes in the tree is $\frac{1- n^{layers}}{1-n}$ which evaluates to $n^{c}$.